# Background color of the block of text

Tags: pdftex, color, boxes, backgrounds

I want to have something like given in the picture. Borders above and below of the box are optional. I tried `\colorbox`, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,249,227}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
Following are some items:
\colorbox{bg}{\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,249,227}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With upper and lower lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,249,227}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
enhanced jigsaw,
%oversize,
colback=bg,
boxrule=0pt,
overlay unbroken and first ={%
\draw[line width=0.2pt,double=bg,draw=bg!70!black,
    double distance=1pt,] (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east);
\draw[line width=0.2pt,double=bg,draw=bg!70!black,
    double distance=1pt,] (frame.south west) -- (frame.south east);},
breakable,
arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
#1}%


\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{mybox}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]